# Beginner jQuery question, checkboxes in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I'm just starting to try and use abit of jQuery in my app to change some css depending on if a checkbox is checked or not, I'm starting with this bit of code in my view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {  
    if($("#area-1").is(':checked')) {
      alert('checked!');
    } else {
      alert('not checked!');
    }
  });
</script>
```

And this is what is displayed for my checkboxes in the source:

```
<div class="filter_options_container">
  <form class="form">      
    <fieldset class="filter_form_fieldset areas">
      <input id="area-1" name="areas[]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
        <label for="area-1"><p1>Area1</p1></label>

      <input id="area-2" name="areas[]" type="checkbox" value="2" />
        <label for="area-2"><p1>Area2</p1></label>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="form_filter_button">
      <p2><input type="submit" value="Filter"/></p2>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

**edit**
Rails view code for the form:

```
<div class="filter_options_container">
  <form class="form">

    <fieldset class="filter_form_fieldset areas">
      <% Area.all.each do |a| %>
      <%= check_box_tag 'areas[]', a.id, false, :id => "area-#{a.id}" %>
        <label for="area-<%= a.id %>"><p1><%= a.name %></p1></label>
      <% end %>
    </fieldset>

    <div class="form_filter_button">
      <p2><input type="submit" value="Filter"/></p2>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

I was expecting it to give an alert message saying 'checked' when checking the area1 box and submitting the form but it only returns 'not checked' why is this?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're missing an event handler bound to the `change/click*` event of the `area-1` element. The code as you have it will only call the alert when the DOM has loaded and not when the value has changed. I think you want something like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {  
    $("#area-1").click(function() {
      alert(this.checked? 'checked!' : 'not checked!');
    });
  });
</script>
```

**[Example code](http://jsfiddle.net/hWArc/)** for you to have a play with

**the [change event does not fire at the same point in time across browsers](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/change.html) so the click event is recommended instead. However, jQuery fixes this problem across browsers.*

Answer (score 1):

If you want something to happen when the checkbox is clicked you will need to register an event handler to the checkbox.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  $("#area-1").click(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
      alert('checked!');
    } else {
      alert('not checked!');
    }
  });
});
```

If you want the logic to fire on form submit you can register a function on `$("form").submit();`

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    if ($("#area-1").is(':checked')) {
        alert('checked!');
    } else {
        alert('not checked!');
    }
});
```

Example of this on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dEm5r/1/).

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer it works great! Sorry I cant tick 2 answers

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {  
    if($("#area-1:checked").length > 0) {
      alert('checked!');
    } else {
      alert('not checked!');
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for the speedy reply it still wont work though, i'll add into my question the rails code in the view whats generating the checkboxes, maybe the way in which the id's are generated is breaking it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are calling function when the document is ready. Initially check bos is not checked so it always return "not checked!". If you want to do this you may want to listen to submit button the evaluate the checked status.